# MongoDB :How to query the item in a list of itmes that is list type?

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

Test Code:

```
[
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "4e27f4c0cfdb4a09b8ace1dd"
    },
    "Description": "NO.000001",
    "Title": "PM:000001",
    "Age": 14,
    "CommentList": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "4e27f4c0cfdb4a09b8ace1da"
            },
            "Content": "Hello:00001",
            "Creator": "Jack00001",
            "Date": "2011-7-21 0:00:00",
            "InDate": {
                "$date": 1310400000000
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "4e27f4c0cfdb4a09b8ace1db"
            },
            "Content": "Hello:00002",
            "Creator": "Jack00002",
            "Date": "2011-7-21 0:00:00",
            "InDate": {
                "$date": 1310400000000
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "4e27f4c0cfdb4a09b8ace1dc"
            },
            "Content": "Hello:00003",
            "Creator": "Jack00003",
            "Date": "2011-7-21 0:00:00",
            "InDate": {
                "$date": 1310400000000
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

]

I use the mongodb c# driver,and based on the data model, my expected results is that:

```
[
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "4e27f4c0cfdb4a09b8ace1dd"
    },
    "Description": "NO.000001",
    "Title": "PM:000001",
    "Age": 14,
    "CommentList": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "4e27f4c0cfdb4a09b8ace1db"
            },
            "Content": "Hello:00002",
            "Creator": "Jack00002",
            "Date": "2011-7-21 0:00:00",
            "InDate": {
                "$date": 1310400000000
            }
        },
    ...
    ]
}
```

]

How to get the comment?Thanks!

Comment: Your question need clarification. Do you need all comments or only some comments? Based on that I may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, it is [not possible](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/4e6f5a0bac1abccc) for now to select a embedded document. Using LINQ on cursor you can filter the result:

```
var query = Query.And(new[] { Query.EQ("_id.$oid", documentId), Query.EQ("CommentList._id.$oid", commentId) });
var res = collection.FindOne(query);
res = res.Select(o=> new DocumentName 
{
  Description = o.Description,
  ....
  CommentList = o.CommentList.Where(x=>x.Id == commentId)
});
```

Comment: Just to update this, it is no longer true that embedded documents can't be used as criteria for a query: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch